# How do Python's string and unicode coercion/magic functions work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, coercion

I'm using Python version: 2.7.3.

In Python, we use the magic methods `__str__` and `__unicode__` to define the behavior of `str` and `unicode` on our custom classes:

```
>>> class A(object):
  def __str__(self):
    print 'Casting A to str'
    return u'String'
  def __unicode__(self):
    print 'Casting A to unicode'
    return 'Unicode'


>>> a = A()
>>> str(a)
Casting A to str
'String'
>>> unicode(a)
Casting A to unicode
u'Unicode'
```

The behavior suggests that the return value from `__str__` and `__unicode__` is coerced to either `str` or `unicode` depending on which magic method is run.

However, if we do this:

```
>>> class B(object):
  def __str__(self):
    print 'Casting B to str'
    return A()
  def __unicode__(self):
    print 'Casting B to unicode'
    return A()


>>> b = B()
>>> str(b)
Casting B to str

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#47>", line 1, in <module>
    str(b)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type A)
>>> unicode(b)
Casting B to unicode

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#48>", line 1, in <module>
    unicode(b)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, A found
```

Calling `str.mro()` and `unicode.mro()` says that both are subclasses of `basestring`.  However, `__unicode__` also allows returning of `buffer` objects, which directly inherits from `object` and doesn't inherit from `basestring`.

So, my question is, what actually happens when `str` and `unicode` are called?  What are the return value requirements on `__str__` and `__unicode__` for use in `str` and `unicode`?

Comment: You might need to look through the source code to find this out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, `__unicode__` also allows returning of buffer objects, which
>   directly object and don't inherit from basestring.

This is not correct. `unicode()` can convert a string *or a buffer*. It is a "best attempt" at converting the passed argument to unicode using the default encoding (that's why it says *coercing*). It will always return a unicode object.

> So, my question is, what actually happens when str and unicode are
>   called? What are the return value requirements on `__str__` and
>   `__unicode__` for use in str and unicode?

`__str__` should return an informal, human-friendly string representation of the object. This is what is called when someone uses `str()` on your object, or when your object is part of a print statement.

`__unicode__` should always return a *`unicode` object*. If this method is not defined, `__str__` is called and then the results are coerced to unicode (by passing them to `unicode()`).

In your second example, you are returning invalid objects which is why you are seeing the error messages. Your first example appears to work for `__unicode__` because of a side-effect, but it is also not written correctly.

The [data model](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) section of the documentation is worth a read for more information and details on these "magic methods".

Comment: This states what should be returned, but the question (at least my intention was) is why can't you return something else?

Comment: These "magic" methods have a certain protocol associated with them, which is why you get unexpected results if you return something other than what is expected because they are part of the _data model_ of objects.